# Stokes' Theorem Always Surface Independent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Is Stokes' Theorem always surface independent?
In my textbook it says that if F has a vector potential A such that curl(A)=F, then the following is true:

$$\iint F \cdot dS =\int A \cdot dr$$
Excuse the lack of formal notation, I couldn't figure out how to write the circulation symbol.

Anyway, I don't really understand how this is any different than the regular Stokes' theorem. My book says that if a vector field has a vector potential then the result of Stokes' theorem is surface independent give the same boundary and orientation. However, if you substitute in the curl of A  for F, you get:

$$\iint (\nabla\times A) \cdot dS = \int A \cdot dr$$

Compared to the regular Stokes' Theorem this seems exactly the same, just that we replaced the letter F with A.

Regular Theorem:

$$\iint (\nabla \times F) \cdot dS = \int F \cdot dr$$

Vector Potential Version:

$$\iint (\nabla \times A) \cdot dS = \int A \cdot dr$$

Am I missing something here or does this mean that Stokes' Theorem is always surface independent? If so, why would the book bring this up as a different thing? Any help explaining this would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: choice of letters $A$ vs $F$ is obviously irrelevant. The important thing is that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two surfaces with the same boundary $L$ (including orientation) then for any vector field $F$ (call it $A$ if you like, or $B$ or $G$ or $Z$ etc), we have $\int_{S_1}\nabla\times F\,\cdot da=\int_{S_2}\nabla\times F\cdot da$, simply because these are both equal to $\int_{L}F\cdot dr$. In short “surface integral of curl of a vector field over two surfaces with equal boundary is equal”. Of course, if you allow the boundary to change, then the answer might differ.

Comment: Sloppy language. Surface independent among oriented surfaces having the same oriented boundary curve.